# Folder to which i moved my images isn't showing in my gallery app

Tags: java, android, file, gallery

I'm creating a gallery like app where I'm having an option of moving image to a target directory. Image is being moved and source image is getting deleted, but the new folder isn't being listed on my app. In my default gallery app folder is visible with the pics i moved.

```
public void moveToFav(String filePath){

        boolean renameBoolean = false;
        File from = new File(filePath);
        String revName = new StringBuilder(filePath).reverse().toString();
        String array2[]= revName.split("/", 2);
        String realName = new StringBuilder(array2[0]).reverse().toString();

        File to = new File(Function.FAV_PATH+"/"+realName);
        if (from.renameTo(to)){
            getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{filePath});
            LoadAlbum loadAlbum = new LoadAlbum(FullScreenImageActivity.this);
            loadAlbum.execute();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(FullScreenImageActivity.this,"Please retry after sometime..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

This is my AsyncTask where I'm fetching all the images :

```
package com.apps.sumukha.galleri.AsyncTasks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MergeCursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import com.apps.sumukha.galleri.Activities.SplashScreen;
import com.apps.sumukha.galleri.MainActivity;
import com.apps.sumukha.galleri.Utils.Function;
import com.apps.sumukha.galleri.Utils.MapComparator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by sumukha on 4/4/18.
 */

public class LoadAlbum extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Context context;

    public LoadAlbum(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        albumList.clear();
        System.out.println("*****###### cAME to  async");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String xml = "";

        String path = null;
        String album = null;
        String timestamp = null;
        String countPhoto = null;
        Uri uriExternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri uriInternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;


        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED };
        Cursor cursorExternal = context.getContentResolver().query(uriExternal, projection, "_data IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (bucket_display_name",
                null, null);
        Cursor cursorInternal = context.getContentResolver().query(uriInternal, projection, "_data IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (bucket_display_name",
                null, null);
        Cursor cursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursorExternal,cursorInternal});

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
            album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
            timestamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED));
            countPhoto = Function.getCount(context, album);

            albumList.add(Function.mappingInbox(album, path, timestamp, Function.converToTime(timestamp), countPhoto));
        }
        cursor.close();
        Collections.sort(albumList, new MapComparator(Function.KEY_TIMESTAMP, "dsc")); // Arranging photo album by timestamp decending
        return xml;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String xml) {

        System.out.println("****#### post report "+albumList.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("albumlist",albumList);
        context.startActivity(intent);
//            AlbumAdapter adapter = new AlbumAdapter(MainActivity.this, albumList);
//            galleryGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
//            galleryGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
//                                        final int position, long id) {
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlbumActivity.class);
//                    intent.putExtra("name", albumList.get(+position).get(Function.KEY_ALBUM));
//                    startActivity(intent);
//                }
//            });
    }

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are listing. You did not post code.

Comment: Which code you wish to see ? I have a option bar icon on click of which above written function is being called. Filepath of the image is being passed.

Comment: Can you explain that your app moves a file in a folder and then not knows to display that file in that folder?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Please find the whole codebase here :

Comment: https://github.com/SumukhaK/Android_WorkSamples

Comment: If you wanna say or explain something than please do. I will not folow that link.

Comment: in the function above posted, I'm moving image from one file to another. It is moving. But the new folder (lets say X) is not being shown in my app. That's my issue.

Comment: You will have to send a notification to the Media Scanner. are you doing that?

Comment: A different one from what is already present in the method I posted? ( In movtoFav method, after if statement I'm informing content provider regarding deletion).